# How to access Oracle APEX's database using php?

Tags: php, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I just found out that `PHP` and `APEX` contrast each other. What I'd like to do is manipulate the `Oracle` database using `PHP` instead of `APEX`.

The main reason I'd want to do this is to use an Oracle database free of charge.

Comment: This question is not specific enough to answer.

Comment: Sure, you can use PHP to access an Oracle database.  I'm not sure I see a question, though.  Are you asking for a tutorial on using Oracle and PHP?  If so, a simple Google search on "Oracle PHP" returns a number of hits including the Underground PHP and Oracle Manual http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, you might find this useful:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php

Also see the documentation of the other related functions used in the codes of that page (they can be found in that site as well).

You might need some other tools like Oracle SQL Developer, or TOAD for Oracle - to do some of the initial database manipulation works (i.e - unlocking users) and other related tasks (like manually executing queries to check the correctness of the query, checking whether the database / table getting modified / updated / altered according to the application logic).